# Finding adjacent cells in a 2D-grid with increasing radius

Tags: algorithm, search

Let there be a 2D-grid where X is the cell to be examined and T is a cell that satisties the examined criteria for the given cell X.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| T |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | X |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Now I want to find the closest cell to X that satisfies the criteria (T in this example) by searching in the following way, where the numbers indicate the cell to be examined in increasing order:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 11|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 10| 1 | 2 | 3 |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 9 | 0 | X | 4 |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The simple approach to hard-code the offsets from the X-Cell doesn't work, because the distance between T and X is arbitrarily. So how can I archieve this without the former approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test for a radius is not specified yet, above loop does not mark anything, it just fills a square. The term "radius" is only appropriate for circular regions.

If you want to enumerate points residing inside or near a circle, you use **Euclidian distance**:

- In float domain: currentRadius * currentRadius as condition and multiply X * X + Y * Y accordingly
- in integer domain: a Bresenham circle, ref https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bresenhams-circle-drawing-algorithm/ connect horizontal for a fill

The second option is fastest - I used it in the good old days - and you will find the points faster.. but it leaves you with quadrant and boundary issues, and if you're storing points the gain in runtime from integer compares will be irrelevant.

Nowadays, I'd use the first option. For relatively small grids, use the loop, add the test for R * R > V, where V is squared Euclidian distance between X and T, which is V = (T.X-X) * (T.X-X) + (T.Y-Y) * (T.Y-Y) for each point.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get neighbours there is a simple algorithm shown below. Radius will specify how many neighbours you will get and it can be incremented very simply. It will go from top to bottom left to right. With the data its just a matter of looping threw each one of the neighbours and getting adjacent cells that are -1 apart

```
 List<Node> neighbours = new List<Node>();

  iint currentRadius = 1;
  for(int x = -currentRadius; x <= concurrent; x++)
  {
    for(int y = -currentRadius; y <= concurrent; y++)
    {
      if(x == 0 && y == 0)
        continue; //Dont check itself

      int checkX = pos.x + x;
      int checkY = pos.y + y;

      if(checkX >= 0 && checkX < gridSizeX && checkY >= 0 checkY < gridSizeY) //Check if current pos is not out of bounds
      {
        neighbours.Add(nodes(checkX, checkY));
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: not exactly what I was looking, but it gave me an idea on how to approach the problem now, thanks :)

Comment: Yeah i might have gotten the question wrong.. My bad.You can solve this problem by having 4 directions - when you hit a wall switch directions like shown in your example - keep doing it while you're not at your given destination. I remember having this exact problem during my senior year at programming contest.